# Raspberry Pi 3 GPIO LED circuit not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, hardware

I am just getting into hardware programming with my Raspberry Pi 3, and I am working on a simple LED program. [This is a picture of my circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHOVB.jpg)

This is my code, which I am running with with the terminal command `sudo python LED_TEST_7.py`:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
pinNum = 18
GPIO.setmode(BCM)
GPIO.setup(pinNum, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(pinNum, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The code runs without errors, and the circuit works when hooked up to a 9v battery. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  What do you observe happening?  What is the question?

Comment: This code quite probably did turn on your LED - for about a millisecond, before the ``cleanup()`` call undid everything you'd done.  You need a ``time.sleep`` in there, or some other sort of delay.

Comment: The RPi GPIO are only 3.3V so if your resistor is sized to work at 9V it may not be allowing enough current at 3.3V to turn on the LED

Answer (score 0):

If between `GPIO.output(pinNum, GPIO.HIGH)` and `GPIO.cleanup()` you put a delay? Maybe the transition is very fast.

E.g:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
pinNum = 18
GPIO.setmode(BCM)
GPIO.setup(pinNum, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(pinNum, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.4)
GPIO.cleanup()
```